# pass Ckeditor value to div text without html tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have Ckeditor in my view and I dynamicly get editor value and show them in divs. I tried many combinaiton of defining(val,html,tex, etc) like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
        e.editor.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
            $("#mirror1").text(str);
            $("#mirror2").val(str);
            $("#mirror3").html(str);
            $('#mirror4').val($('<div/>').html(str).text());
        }
      );
    });
});
```

my divs

```
<div id="mirror1">
</div>
<div id="mirror2">
</div>
<div id="mirror3">
</div>
<div id="mirror4">
</div>
```

for exaple When I wrote `<pre>int i=0;</pre>`

```
mirror1 text= &lt;pre&gt;deneme&lt;/pre&gt;
mirror2 text= null
mirror3 text= <pre>int i=0;</pre>
mirror4 text= null
```

I m expecting output: `int i=0;`

How may I do this.What is the correct syntax?. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you skip the jQuery part, you can do it with simple javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
        e.editor.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
            document.getElementById("mirror1").innerHTML = str;
        }
      );
    });
 });
```

But using the DOM keyup event might not be enough if you want a good mirror, I suggest you to use the [onChange plugin for CKEditor](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) (disclaimer: I wrote it) and now the mirror will update whenever the content changes:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    var mirror2 = document.getElementById("mirror2");
    e.editor.on('change', function () {
        mirror2.innerHTML = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I deal 2 days to do this. I did it. I wish I asked 2 days ago. Thanks