# ckeditor change generated output for paragraph element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Our application uses ckeditor to generate user friendly email content to send email to clients. Email content is prepared by business people so they don't know any html at all.

So I want ckeditor to add inline style to paragraphs(`<p>` elements) such as `<p style="line-height:20px;">` automatically instead of just generating `<p>`.

Since the generated output is emailed I don't have any chance to use CSS file.
I tried to wrap `<p>` elements within `<table>` but I couldn't change "**line-height**" property in that way, since email sites like gmail, yahoo have already their own styling for `<p>` elements. I must use inline style for each `<p>` element I think and I don't know how to achieve this.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a setting or quick code modification to do this.

Here are Two approaches.

**If you would like to annoy your users do this (see AlfonsoML's comment):**
If you would like the flexibility to do more than the `<p>` styling as the content is updated in the editor, the best approach would likely be to use the "onchange" plugin created by @AlfonsoML. You can download it here:
[onChange event for CKEditor](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html)

He demonstrates how to use it to show the editor content in another `<div>` here:
[pass Ckeditor value to div text without html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371207/751619)

---

After installing the plugin, you could do something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
    e.editor.on('change', function () {
        var editorContent = CKEDITOR.instances['TextAreaID'].getData();
        editorContent.replace('<p>', '<p style="line-height:20px;">');
        CKEDITOR.instances['TextAreaID'].setData(editorContent);
    });
});
```

---

**Better Approach:**
If you only want to do the `<p>` styling and prefer to avoid the overhead of running that function every time the content changes, you could load a stylesheet to apply the style to the `<p>` elements within the editor with this config setting:

```
config.contentsCss = '/css/mysitestyles.css';
```

Then use an `onsubmit` function with your form. Something like this:

```
<form name="ff" id="ff" action="xx" method="POST" onsubmit="return doSubmit();">
```

The function:

```
function doSubmit() {
    var emailContent = $('textarea#TextAreaID').val();        
    emailContent.replace('<p>', '<p style="line-height:20px;">');
    $('textarea#TextAreaID').val(editorContent);
};
```

Comment: Certainly the first way is one of the best ways to piss your users. If you try to replace the whole HTML whenever there's a change they will lose selection, the caret position, the undo will become crazy... The second approach is much more reasonable.

Comment: @AlfonsoML Thanks for the insight, I haven't used the onchange plugin in this fashion and didn't realize the implications.

Comment: @AlfonsoML I know you're very knowledgeable about CkEditor, jQuery, JavaScript, etc. Please don't hesitate to comment if I post something that is wrong or that could be improved. That gives me a chance to learn and fix it, which is better than having a mistake that shows up for eternity.

Comment: I know a bit about CKEditor because I've worked for very long with it, and a very good way to learn anything is to behave like you do and try to understand the problems of other people and try to help them. That forces anyone to think about new problems and learn new tricks.